# Swift ui macos background transparent TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

As you can see from the image I have a `TextField` and after `list`.

The list has a transparent background, I'm using `.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())`.

But how do I get a transparent background where the `TextField` is located.

Code:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {

    TextField("Username", text: $username)
    .padding(.leading, 20)
    .padding(.trailing, 20)
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.3)
        )
        .padding(.leading, 20)
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
    )
    .padding(.top)
    .padding(.bottom)

    List(restaurants) { restaurant in
        RestaurantRow(restaurant: restaurant)
    }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())

}.padding(0)
.frame(width: 400.0, height: 400.0, alignment: .top)
```

Comment: Transparent background for what?

Comment: @Asperi: Where there is the input field with the word leo, behind the input field there is that dark background you see it, I would like that to be transparent like the one you see in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need visual effect view in background (it is used by default for sidebar styled lists)

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.6

[image: demo]

```
struct VisualEffectView: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView {
        let view = NSVisualEffectView()

        view.blendingMode = .behindWindow    // << important !!
        view.isEmphasized = true
        view.material = .appearanceBased
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

and put it to needed area, in this case below `TextField`

```
    TextField("Username", text: $username)
    .padding(.leading, 20)
    .padding(.trailing, 20)
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.3)
        )
        .padding(.leading, 20)
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
    )
    .padding(.top)
    .padding(.bottom)
    .background(VisualEffectView())
```

Comment: Thx, it seems to work, so every element I put in must have that right background?
I found this:
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/visual-design/translucency/

Comment: You can make it common background view for entire content view if you want.

Comment: You say by modifying the AppDelegate?

Comment: No, rather `ContentView`.

Comment: I can ask you how, why `.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())` is giving me a strange problem on the list, so I would like to take it off.

Comment: macos app crashes as soon as it receives data.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Am I missing something? The visual effect view is surrounding the text field however the text field itself still show with white background.

Answer (score -2):

You could use on the background Color.white.opacity(0.01) or Color.clear in your case:

```
     .background(
       RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
       .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.01))
```

or

```
      .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
        .fill(Color.clear))
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm talking about the dark part where the textfield.

Comment: What do you have behind Textfield, the list is after isn't?

Comment: This doesn't work. Like Paul I'm trying to set the background.